# The system cannot find the path specified while starting Android SDK Manager

Tags: android

While installing the Android SDK in Eclipse by Windows->preferences->android.
It continuously shows the error [SDK manager] The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the android sdk first and then go to

> windows-> preferences -> android

and set the path of the sdk you have downloaded. 
That's it!

Comment: I already did that more than once.But problem still the same.

Comment: But after sometime console shows new error DDMS files not found:D:\...\platformtools\hprof-conv.exe

Comment: go to the location mentioned : `D:\...\platformtools\hprof-conv.exe` , if the file is there then restart your eclipse. That should solve the issue, it happens sometimes

Comment: It is present at tools.